# tkinter for Text Summarization

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, nlp, pycharm

I am trying to make a simple Text Summarization GUI that takes an input text and generates the summary. While the program is running absolutely fine, I am getting errors in converting it into exe file. Following are two the main programs for the GUI interface-

```
import tkinter
import gensim
from tkinter import 
from gensim.summarization import summarize

#create windows object
root=Tk()
root.geometry("1024x800") #set the window size using .geometry command
root.title("AUTOMATED TEXT SUMMARIZER")
h1=Label(root,text="AUTOMATED TEXT SUMMARIZER FOR ENGLISH",font= 
("arial",12,"bold"),fg="#26482B").pack()

#set the label, like 'enter text'  
l1 = Label(root,text="Enter Some Text", font= 
("arial",10,"bold"),fg="#26482B").place(x=10,y=50)
#take some text as input in the textbox
inp = Text(root,width=100,height=30,bg="white",font=("arial",8,"bold"))
inp.place(x=10,y=90)
#set another label that indicates the results
l2 = Label(root,text="Summary", font= 
("arial",10,"bold"),fg="#26482B").place(x=720,y=50)


opt = Text(root,width=50,height=20,bg="white",font=("arial",10,"bold"))
opt.place(x=640,y=90)

def sum():
    txt = inp.get("1.0", END)
    output = summarize(txt, ratio=0.2)
    opt.insert(0.0, output)

        button_a = Button(root,text="Generate 
         Summary",width=30,height=2,bg="#9B9D9C",fg="black",font= 
    ("arial",9,"bold"),command=sum)
 button_a.place(x=120,y=600)

def clear():
    inp.delete("1.0",END)
    opt.delete("1.0",END)

button_b= 
Button(root,text="Clear",width=18,height=2,bg="#9B9D9C",fg="black",font= 
("arial",9,"bold"),command=clear)
button_b.place(x=450,y=600)


root.mainloop()
```

This is the setup_file.py-

```
import os
import cx_Freeze
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable
import sys


os.environ['TCL_LIBRARY'] = "C:/LOCAL_TO_PYTHON/PYTHON35-32/tcl/tcl86t.dll"
os.environ['TK_LIBRARY'] = "C:/LOCAL_TO_PYTHON/PYTHON35-32/tcl/tk86t.dll"

includefiles = ['C:/Users/praty/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python36- 
32/DLLs/tcl86t.dll','C:/Users/praty/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python36- 
32/DLLs/tk86t.dll']
includes = []
packages = ['tkinter','gensim']
additional_mods = ['numpy.core._methods', 'numpy.lib.format']
build_exe_options = 
{'includes':includes,'includes':additional_mods,'packages':packages, 
'include_files':includefiles}

base = None

if sys.platform == 'win32':
    base = "Win32GUI"
elif sys.platform == 'win64':
    base = 'Win64GUI'

setup(  name = 'text summarizer',
        version = '0.1',
        description = 'generate summary',
        options = {'build_exe': build_exe_options},
        executables = [Executable('Automated_Text_Summarizer.py', base=base)]
        )
```

This is the error I am getting:

[image: This the error related to the program]

Comment: [Error text trapped in images](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/) is not ideal on technical Q&A sites. Images are not compatible with screen-readers, clipboards or search engines, and thus they make it harder for readers to help you. Please copy the text from that dialogue box and paste it, using the code formatting tool, into the question. Thank you.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.